# Slow execution in Fourier analysis

Tags: performance-tuning, fourier-analysis

The following example executes and plots a Fourier transform of a integrable function. Can anyone suggests why the execution is so slow (about 1 min on a laptop Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-4600U CPU @ 2.10GHz with 7GiB  RAM free) ?

```
ClearAll[x,t,ω,A,X,t];
Print["Signal Exp[-at]Unistep[t]"]
a:=1;
F[x_]:=Exp[-a x]UnitStep[x];
Plot[F[x],{x,-10,10},PlotRange->All]
Print["Fourier spectral analysis"]
A[ω_]:=FourierTransform[F[t],t,ω];
Print["Given that the result is a complex function we print the square abs value (i.e. an intensity)"]
Plot[Abs[A[x]]^2,{x,-10,10}, PlotRange->All]
```

Comment: You are evaluating a _symbolic_ Fourier transform for each plot point. Get the symbolic result once, then re-use it.

Comment: @Szabolcs: I see thanks for the hint!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since the symbolic Fourier transform can be evaluated, it is a much better idea to use `Set` (`=`) instead of `SetDelayed` (`:=`). This way, the symbolic computations have to be done only once this way:

```
ClearAll[x, t, \[Omega], A, X, t];
Print["Signal Exp[-at]Unistep[t]"]
a = 1;
F[x_] = Exp[-a x] UnitStep[x];
Plot[F[x], {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
Print["Fourier spectral analysis"]
A[\[Omega]_] = FourierTransform[F[t], t, \[Omega]];
Print["Given that the result is a complex function we print the \
square abs value (i.e. an intensity)"]
Plot[Abs[A[x]]^2, {x, -10, 10}, PlotRange -> All]
```

The plot is now created within 40 ms on my machine.

To make it more explicit: With `SetDelayed`,
the *symbolic* computation `FourierTransform[F[t], t, x]` is executed each time `A[x]` is called. And it is called hundreds if not thousand times from the `Plot` command. One has to keep in mind that symbolic computations are *much* slower than pure number crunching of machine precision numbers.

However, you are lucky, because `FourierTransform[F[t], t, x]` has a closed form expression for symbolic `x`. So it suffices to compute it *once* and to store the resulting expression in a function. That is what

```
A[x_] = FourierTransform[F[t], t, x];
```

does. Alternatively, you may use

```
A[x_] := Evalute[FourierTransform[F[t], t, x]];
```

or

```
A = Function[x , FourierTransform[F[t], t, x]]];
```

Now, when calling `A[x]` with a floating point number, it is now only about number crunching; this is why it becomes much faster.

Comment: I agree, the modified code is fast for me also. In order to accept the answer can you elaborate on the following though: 1) what in English "can be evaluates" means, 2) can you explain for all readers why in essence ":=" is different from "=" in Mathematica and why it implies taking more time?